# What's wrong with this flex code?

Tags: compiler-construction, flex-lexer

i am trying to compile this flex code.

```
  %{

#include <stdlib.h>
#include "y.tab.h"

%}
digit [0-9]
letter [A-Za-z]
point [.]

%%
{digit}+{{point}{digit+}}?   {printf("Number\n");}
{letter}+   {printf("ID\n");}
("hi"|"oi"|"swagatam")"\n"    { printf("START\n"); /*return HI;*/  }
("tchau"|"bye"|"biday")"\n"   { printf("END\n"); /*return BYE;*/ }
%.                    { yyerror();  }

%%

int main(void)
{
   //yyparse();
   yylex();
   return 0;
}

int yywrap(void)
{  
   return 0;
}

int yyerror(void)
{
    printf("Error\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

when I compiled this code it shows "hello.l", line 12: unrecognized rule
in line 12 the code is-

```
 {digit}+{{point}{digit+}}?   {printf("Number\n");}
```

this part. Can anyone tell me what's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{digit}+{{point}{digit+}}?   {printf("Number\n");}
```

`{}` is used to refer to definitions, not for grouping. They're supposed to contain the name of the definition and nothing else. So `{{point}{digit+}}` is ill-formed because `{point}{digit+}` is not a valid name for a definition.

So the outer `{}` should be `()` instead and the `+` for `digit` should be outside of the `{}`:

```
{digit}+({point}{digit}+)?   {printf("Number\n");}
```